# Holding keys doesn't work - Fedora 26 Gnome

Tags: keyboard, fedora, gnome, gnome3, input

Since two system updates before i started to notice that when i hold a key it repeats just a few times and randomly stops.

Example (I'm holding a key and when it stops I move to the next one).

aaaaaaasdfggghjkkkkkkl

As I said before since a system update I noticed but I'm not sure that's the problem. It could be a ghost character or someting because when I'm in the terminal an scroll up i sends me at the bottom like when I write something.

I'm using Fedora 26 and gnome and Microsoft bluetooth mouse and keyboard. I not sure how to find out what's wrong hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with new system update.

I'm still not really sure what the problem was.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  If you accept your own answer (click the checkmark next to it), that will indicate that the problem has been solved.